# how to convert list <int> chain to csv in c#

Tags: c#

There is a list of integers, I want to store the list in csv. So every time there is a new chain code it will add it after the previous data.

```
public void ExportCsv(List<int> chain, string _path = null)
    {
        if(_path==null) _path = UnityEngine.Application.persistentDataPath;
        string filePath = _path + "/output.csv";
        //Debug.Log("PATHc" + fileName);
        string csv = String.Join(",", chain.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
        //Debug.Log("CSV " + csv);
        ....

    }
```

```
list of integers: 3 3 3 1 5 2
in csv
3 3 3 1 5 2
then added a new chain 3 2 3 1
in csv to be
333152
3231
```

[image]

Comment: use csvhelper, open the file in append mode

Comment: I dont think this is how SO works. Can you show us some examples of code you've written to solve the issue and what issues you faced?

Comment: Those are whole numbers in one cell? Are those supposed to be split into single digits for CSV? This is _really_ unclear.

Comment: BTW Excel can save to CSV natively. Not sure if Office libs can utilize that functionality and if so, which ones.

Answer (score 0):

Recently i had similar problem with Newlines. But i did it manually:

```
data += line + Environment.NewLine;
```

Then i needed to remove it:

```
data = data.TrimEnd(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
```

Hope it will help